# How to make snap app visible on "Open with"?

Tags: ubuntu, snapcraft

I have successfully created a snap package and it works fine. I've also created a .desktop file for the app. But when I install the snap app, the .desktop file is not automatically copied to "usr/share/applications" folder, which is were it must be so the user can choose the app when using "Open with". I have read the snapcraft documentation but couldn't find any answer for that. How could I make the app visible on "Open with"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's a bit hidden in the documentation under "[Commands, daemons, & assets](https://snapcraft.io/docs/build-snaps/metadata#fixed-assets)". Just below the `command:` line for your application, add a `desktop:` line that specifies the path to the .desktop file inside the snap.

Comment: I already have a desktop file inside snap/gui folder. That should do the trick, right? I also tried to specify it manually like you explained, but neither way my application is visible under "Open with" option in Ubuntu. If I create the .desktop file manually and paste it into applications folder it work, but that's not user-friendly